Are there any rules governing the variation between codaic /n/ and nasal vowels in Hindustani?
Are there any rules governing when a vowel + /n/ combination in Hindustani will become a nasal vowel, or are they completely separate and unpredictable? If so, are there any minimal pairs to prove so? Is it that they are unpredictable in some environments but predictable in others? At first I thought that short vowels will never be nasalised and long vowels will only be nasalised in certain environments, but it was difficult for me to form a list of rules describing when and when not such would happen. I thought of "in word final syllables with only one other codaic consonant, long vowels would be nasalised, and in other environments, either could occur", but I dont know exactly how well that holds up.
